# Coercion with multiple arguments

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

From [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-18.html):

> **Exercise 2.82**
>
> Show how to generalize
>   apply-generic to handle coercion in
>   the general case of multiple
>   arguments. One strategy is to attempt
>   to coerce all the arguments to the
>   type of the first argument, then to
>   the type of the second argument, and
>   so on. Give an example of a situation
>   where this strategy (and likewise the
>   two-argument version given above) is
>   not sufficiently general. (Hint:
>   Consider the case where there are some
>   suitable mixed-type operations present
>   in the table that will not be tried.)

I wrote this part before:

```
(define fn-registry '())
(define (get op param-types)
  (define (rec entry . rest)
    (define (all-equal a b)
      (if (symbol? a)
          (eq? a b)
          (and (= (length a) (length b))
               (let loop ((x a) (y b))
                 (or (null? x)
                     (and (eq? (car x) (car y))
                          (loop (cdr x) (cdr y))))))))
    (let ((op-entry (car entry))
          (param-types-entry (cadr entry))
          (function-entry (caddr entry)))
      (if (and (eq? op-entry op)
               (all-equal param-types-entry param-types))
          function-entry
          (if (null? rest)
              false
              (apply rec rest)))))
  (apply rec fn-registry))

(define (put op param-types fn)
  (set! fn-registry (cons (list op param-types fn) fn-registry)))
```

I wrote this coercion-registry code for this exercise:

```
(define coercion-registry '())
(define (put-coercion t1 t2 fn) (set! coercion-registry (cons (list t1 t2 fn) coercion-registry)))
(define (get-coercion t1 t2)
  (define (rec entry . reg)
    (define t1-entry car)
    (define t2-entry cadr)
    (define fn-entry caddr)
    (cond ((and (eq? t1 (t1-entry entry))
                (eq? t2 (t2-entry entry))) (fn-entry entry))
          ((null? reg) false)
          (else (apply rec reg))))
  (apply rec coercion-registry))
```

This function takes any set of arguments and coerces them to be the same type:

```
(define (make-set . args)
  (define (rec tested current remains)
    (define (coerce-all to-type result items)
      (if (null? items) 
          result
          (let ((t1->t2 (get-coercion (type-tag (car items)) to-type)))
            (cond ((eq? (type-tag (car items)) to-type) 
                   (coerce-all to-type (cons (car items) result) (cdr items)))
                  ((not t1->t2) false)
                  (else
                   (coerce-all to-type (append result (list (t1->t2 (car items)))) (cdr items)))))))
    (let ((coerced-all (coerce-all (type-tag current)
                                   '()
                                   (append tested (cons current remains)))))
      (cond (coerced-all coerced-all)
            ((null? remains) false)
            (else (rec (append tested (list current)) (car remains) (cdr remains))))))
  (rec '() (car args) (cdr args)))
```

I made some changes to apply-generic as well:

```
(define (apply-generic op . args)      
  (let ((type-tags (map type-tag args)))
    (let ((proc (get op type-tags)))
      (if proc
          (apply proc (map contents args))
          (let ((coerced-args (apply make-set args)))
            (if coerced-args
                (apply apply-generic (cons op coerced-args))
                (error "No method found for these types" (list op type-tags))))))))
```

This came from a previous activity:

```
(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (attach-tag type-tag contents)
  (if (or (symbol? contents) (number? contents))
      contents
      (cons type-tag contents)))

(define (type-tag datum)
  (cond ((pair? datum) (car datum))
        ((number? datum) 'scheme-number)
        ((symbol? datum) 'scheme-symbol)
        (else (error "Bad tagged datum -- TYPE-TAG" datum))))

(define (contents datum)
  (cond ((pair? datum) (cdr datum))
        ((or (number? datum)
             (symbol? datum)) datum)
        (else (error "Bad tagged datum -- CONTENTS" datum))))


(define (add x y) (apply-generic 'add x y))
(define (sub x y) (apply-generic 'sub x y))
(define (mul x y) (apply-generic 'mul x y))
(define (div x y) (apply-generic 'div x y))
(define (equ? x y) (apply-generic 'equ? x y))
(define (=zero? x) (apply-generic '=zero? x))

(define (install-scheme-number-package)
  (define (tag x)
    (attach-tag 'scheme-number x))    
  (put 'add '(scheme-number scheme-number)
       (lambda (x y) (tag (+ x y))))
  (put 'sub '(scheme-number scheme-number)
       (lambda (x y) (tag (- x y))))
  (put 'mul '(scheme-number scheme-number)
       (lambda (x y) (tag (* x y))))
  (put 'div '(scheme-number scheme-number)
       (lambda (x y) (tag (/ x y))))
  (put 'make 'scheme-number
       (lambda (x) (tag x)))
  (put 'equ? '(scheme-number scheme-number) =)
  (put '=zero? '(scheme-number) zero?)
  'done)

(define (make-scheme-number n)
  ((get 'make 'scheme-number) n))

(define (install-rational-package)
  ;; internal procedures
  (define (numer x) (car x))
  (define (denom x) (cdr x))
  (define (make-rat n d)
    (let ((g (gcd n d)))
      (cons (/ n g) (/ d g))))
  (define (add-rat x y)
    (make-rat (+ (* (numer x) (denom y))
                 (* (numer y) (denom x)))
              (* (denom x) (denom y))))
```

I added just this one function as part of what I needed in order to test apply-generic:

```
(put 'add-em '(rational rational rational rational) (lambda (a b c d) (add-rat a (add-rat b (add-rat c d)))))
```

More code from a previous activity:

```
  (define (sub-rat x y)
    (make-rat (- (* (numer x) (denom y))
                 (* (numer y) (denom x)))
              (* (denom x) (denom y))))
  (define (mul-rat x y)
    (make-rat (* (numer x) (numer y))
              (* (denom x) (denom y))))
  (define (div-rat x y)
    (make-rat (* (numer x) (denom y))
              (* (denom x) (numer y))))
  (define (equ?-rat x y)
    (and (= (numer x) (numer y))
         (= (denom x) (denom y))))
  (define (=zero?-rat x) (zero? (numer x)))
  ;; interface to rest of the system
  (define (tag x) (attach-tag 'rational x))
  (put 'add '(rational rational)
       (lambda (x y) (tag (add-rat x y))))
  (put 'sub '(rational rational)
       (lambda (x y) (tag (sub-rat x y))))
  (put 'mul '(rational rational)
       (lambda (x y) (tag (mul-rat x y))))
  (put 'div '(rational rational)
       (lambda (x y) (tag (div-rat x y))))
  (put 'equ? '(rational rational) equ?-rat)
  (put '=zero? '(rational) =zero?-rat)

  (put 'make 'rational
       (lambda (n d) (tag (make-rat n d))))
  'done)
(define (make-rational n d)
  ((get 'make 'rational) n d))

(define (real-part z) (apply-generic 'real-part z))
(define (imag-part z) (apply-generic 'imag-part z))
(define (magnitude z) (apply-generic 'magnitude z))
(define (angle z) (apply-generic 'angle z))
(define (install-complex-package)
  ;; imported procedures from rectangular and polar packages
  (define (make-from-real-imag x y)
    ((get 'make-from-real-imag 'rectangular) x y))
  (define (make-from-mag-ang r a)
    ((get 'make-from-mag-ang 'polar) r a))
  ;; internal procedures
  (define (add-complex z1 z2)
    (make-from-real-imag (+ (real-part z1) (real-part z2))
                         (+ (imag-part z1) (imag-part z2))))
  (define (sub-complex z1 z2)
    (make-from-real-imag (- (real-part z1) (real-part z2))
                         (- (imag-part z1) (imag-part z2))))
  (define (mul-complex z1 z2)
    (make-from-mag-ang (* (magnitude z1) (magnitude z2))
                       (+ (angle z1) (angle z2))))
  (define (div-complex z1 z2)
    (make-from-mag-ang (/ (magnitude z1) (magnitude z2))
                       (- (angle z1) (angle z2))))
  (define (equ?-complex z1 z2)
    (and (= (real-part z1) (real-part z2))
         (= (imag-part z1) (imag-part z2))))
  (define (=zero?-complex z) (and (zero? (real-part z))
                                  (zero? (imag-part z))))
  ;; interface to rest of the system
  (define (tag z) (attach-tag 'complex z))
  (put 'add '(complex complex)
       (lambda (z1 z2) (tag (add-complex z1 z2))))
  (put 'sub '(complex complex)
       (lambda (z1 z2) (tag (sub-complex z1 z2))))
  (put 'mul '(complex complex)
       (lambda (z1 z2) (tag (mul-complex z1 z2))))
  (put 'div '(complex complex)
       (lambda (z1 z2) (tag (div-complex z1 z2))))
  (put 'make-from-real-imag 'complex
       (lambda (x y) (tag (make-from-real-imag x y))))
  (put 'make-from-mag-ang 'complex
       (lambda (r a) (tag (make-from-mag-ang r a))))
  (put 'equ? '(complex complex) equ?-complex)
  (put '=zero? '(complex) =zero?-complex)
  'done)

(define (install-polar-package)
  ;; internal procedures
  (define (magnitude z) (car z))
  (define (angle z) (cdr z))
  (define (make-from-mag-ang r a) (cons r a))
  (define (real-part z)
    (* (magnitude z) (cos (angle z))))
  (define (imag-part z)
    (* (magnitude z) (sin (angle z))))
  (define (make-from-real-imag x y) 
    (cons (sqrt (+ (square x) (square y)))
          (atan y x)))
  (define (equ? x y)
    (and (= (magnitude x) (magnitude y))
         (= (angle x) (angle y))))
  (define (=zero? x) (zero? (magnitude x)))
  ;; interface to the rest of the system
  (define (tag x) (attach-tag 'polar x))
  (put 'real-part '(polar) real-part)
  (put 'imag-part '(polar) imag-part)
  (put 'magnitude '(polar) magnitude)
  (put 'angle '(polar) angle)
  (put 'equ? '(polar polar) equ?)
  (put '=zero? '(polar) =zero?)
  (put 'make-from-real-imag 'polar
       (lambda (x y) (tag (make-from-real-imag x y))))
  (put 'make-from-mag-ang 'polar 
       (lambda (r a) (tag (make-from-mag-ang r a))))
  'done)

(define (install-rectangular-package)
  ;; internal procedures
  (define (real-part z) (car z))
  (define (imag-part z) (cdr z))
  (define (make-from-real-imag x y) (cons x y))
  (define (magnitude z)
    (sqrt (+ (square (real-part z))
             (square (imag-part z)))))
  (define (angle z)
    (atan (imag-part z) (real-part z)))
  (define (make-from-mag-ang r a) 
    (cons (* r (cos a)) (* r (sin a))))
  (define (equ? x y)
    (and (= (real-part x) (real-part y))
         (= (imag-part x) (imag-part y))))
  (define (=zero? x) (and (zero? (real-part x))
                          (zero? (imag-part x))))
  ;; interface to the rest of the system
  (define (tag x) (attach-tag 'rectangular x))
  (put 'real-part '(rectangular) real-part)
  (put 'imag-part '(rectangular) imag-part)
  (put 'magnitude '(rectangular) magnitude)
  (put 'angle '(rectangular) angle)
  (put 'equ? '(rectangular rectangular) equ?)
  (put '=zero? '(rectangular) =zero?)
  (put 'make-from-real-imag 'rectangular 
       (lambda (x y) (tag (make-from-real-imag x y))))
  (put 'make-from-mag-ang 'rectangular 
       (lambda (r a) (tag (make-from-mag-ang r a))))
  'done)

(define (make-complex-from-real-imag x y)
  ((get 'make-from-real-imag 'complex) x y))
(define (make-complex-from-mag-ang r a)
  ((get 'make-from-mag-ang 'complex) r a))

(install-rational-package)
(install-scheme-number-package)
(install-complex-package)
(install-polar-package)
(install-rectangular-package)
```

Register the coercion:

```
(put-coercion 'scheme-number 'rational (lambda (a) (make-rational a 1)))
```

And finally, the test:

```
(apply-generic 'add-em (make-rational 3 4) 2 3 4)
```

There is more code in here than would be necessary to test only the new functionality.  I found it easier to test the new apply-generic by including the code from previous examples.  I'm sorry that it may make it a bit harder to follow exactly what I'm asking here, but please do your best to give me feedback.

How can I improve this code?